# Is not helping a dying PC party member a bad thing?

Tags: dnd-5e, alignment, character-death, party

One of our PCs was down and "bleeding out". It was my turn and no enemies were left alive, I chose not to help my party member due to me believing that my character doesn't care enough due to his past and due to some actions the downed PC took before combat.

This was not taken well by the rest of our group and I quickly agreed that while my chara had some reasons to not help, they wouldn't let people die because of negligence.

However, this got me thinking. Is it always considered an evil deed to not help a downed party memeber? Are there factors that would justify not resuscitating a party member when your alignment is good or neutral?

Comment: Related meta: [are alignment questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357/23970)

Comment: I have voted to close because the references to alignment make this very subjective, especially in an edition which largely eschews the concept. If this could be re-framed as a question about group dynamics or social contract at the table (i.e. with concrete real-world examples) or even in terms of tactical combat, I think it might fly better.

Comment: And to answer that question we would need to know more about the game that's being played. What was discussed beforehand? Why are the PCs together? i.e. What *style* of game are you playing; What's your social contract with your GM and other PCs?

Comment: If you can come up with a reason why you would ignore one of your friends or colleagues while they are on the ground, bleeding out from an accident, and not be considered a horrible person for it, you might have a case. But I don't think you'll find one.

Comment: You might be interested in the question [What is “my guy syndrome” and how do I handle it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37103/34863)